# creating a journal/blog

Tags: untagged

im trying to replace our current journal (excel sheet) with a web portal based journal. something kind of like twitter, but with more options. also needs to have a login so we can track the people entering. it can also be some sort of tool but i cant find anything that meets our demands... i could use a ITIL ticket service but that has way to much functionalities for our use.

im basicly looking for a webportal with a shared blog, where users can login and creat new entries with:

- a topic name
- a automated follow-up ID number
- a field where they can enter specific info
- a reply field
- and a status field with pre defined statuses

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You seem to need some sort of a 'structured' wiki. In a wiki you can have posts link to each other arbitrarily. You also need some tagging mechanism. Sort of a collaborative research wiki. Let us know when you find something good...

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ididwork.com](http://www.ididwork.com/) I like it, for a worklog. It describes itself as a cross between a work log and twitter. It allows for tags and weekly stats generated on stats and time per tag.  It allows you to share your work with co-workers.

Comment: I tried signing up today and got a 500 server error. :(

Comment: @Nic Seems like they are having database problems at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

1st Idea - Yammer
We have started using [Yammer](http://Yammer.com) at work it's like Facebook for the Enterprise but no fields, just freeform data entry with hashtags and searching.

2nd Idea - Twitter updates [from an HTML form](http://ericfickes.com/2009/04/update-twitter-status-from-an-html-form/)

```
<html>
    <form action="http://api.supertweet.net/1/statuses/update.xml" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

        <!-- Set your Super Tweet Username and Password here -->
        <input type="hidden" name="user" value="SUPERTWEET_USERNAME" />
        <input type="hidden" name="pswd" value="SUPERTWEET_PASSWORD" />

        <h4>Update:</h4>
        <textarea name="status" maxlength="140" cols="35" rows="4"></textarea>
        <br><input type="submit" value=" Tweet! " />
    </form>
</html>
```

Then you signup at [supertweet.net/about/documentation](http://supertweet.net) because basic authentication no longer works on twitter.

3rd Idea - Spiceworks Ticket System

You could try a ticket tracking system, I like [Spiceworks](http://spiceworks.com) it's probably more then you need.  But it has some nice reporting capabilities and it allows you to create custom fields and mark them as mandatory.  It also has a time-per-task function and you can report of time used per tasks or type of tasks.  It's very customizable.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds a little confusing however, I'll take my shot. I'm thinking your looking for something like this http://www.joomla.org/ ?

Comment: not exactly what im looking for. best way i can describe is is a "group twitter" where more then one user can add new topics, to which the other users can comment. and when one of the users creates a new topic it will contain the following points: topic name (call subject), automated follow-up ID (connected to database), a text box for the problem, a reply textbox for solutions or other specifications, and a status field with open, hold, test and done. its to replace the call registration we are using now wich is a excel sheet, and a webportal seems to be the best option

Comment: joomla is super complex not at all like the simplicity of the SasS twitter-like software/service.

Comment: That sounds like a ticket-tracking system. Have you consiered one of those?